# Should a Haskell parser allow Unicode digits in numeric literals?

Tags: haskell, syntax, language-lawyer, literals

As an exercise, I am writing a parser for Haskell from scratch. In making the lexer, I noticed the following rules on the [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17700010.2):

> *digit*     → *ascDigit* | *uniDigit*
>   *ascDigit*  →   `0` | `1` | … | `9`
>   *uniDigit*  →   any Unicode decimal digit
>   *octit* →   `0` | `1` | … | `7`
>   *hexit* →   *digit* | `A` | … | `F` | `a` | … | `f`
>
> *decimal* →   *digit*{*digit*}
>   *octal* →   *octit*{*octit*}
>   *hexadecimal*   →   *hexit*{*hexit*}
>
> *integer* →   *decimal*  |    `0o` *octal* | `0O` *octal*  |  `0x` *hexadecimal* | `0X` *hexadecimal*
>   *float* →   *decimal* `.` *decimal* [*exponent*]  | *decimal exponent*
>   *exponent*  →   (`e` | `E`) [`+` | `-`] *decimal*

Decimal and hexadecimal literals, along with float literals, are all based on *digit*, which admits any Unicode decimal digit, instead of *ascDigit*, which admits only the basic digits 0-9 from ASCII. Strangely, *octal* is based on *octit*, which instead only admits the ASCII digits 0-7. I would guess that these "Unicode decimal digit"s are any Unicode codepoints with the "Nd" General Category. However, this includes characters such as the Full-Width digits ０-９ and the Devanagari numerals ०-९. I can see why it might be desirable to allow these in identifiers, but I can see no benefit whatsoever for allowing one to write `९０` for the literal `90`.

GHC seems to agree with me. When I try to compile this file,

```
module DigitTest where
x1 = １
```

it spits out this error.

```
digitTest1.hs:2:6: error: lexical error at character '\65297'
  |
2 | x1 = １
  |      ^
```

However, this file

```
module DigitTest where
x１ = 1
```

compiles just fine. Am I reading the language specification incorrectly? Is GHC's (sensible) behavior actually correct, or does it technically go against the specification in the Report? I can find no mention of this anywhere.

Comment: Funny. I suspect this came about something like “Ok, so literals just consist of ASCII digits, easy.” “No hang on, let's think of internationalisation, Unicode... they also have other digit symbols, right?” “Oh yeah, eh, never dealt with that... but ok, let's insert a clause for that...” “Great.” ...and then it was just forgotten and nobody actually bothered ever implementing it, or noticed that it doesn't make sense to allow mixing different families of digit.

Comment: Yikes. Yeah, don't bother with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the GHC source code file `compiler/parser/Lexer.x`, you can find the following code:

```
ascdigit  = 0-9
$unidigit  = \x03 -- Trick Alex into handling Unicode. See [Unicode in Alex].
$decdigit  = $ascdigit -- for now, should really be $digit (ToDo)
$digit     = [$ascdigit $unidigit]
...
$binit     = 0-1
$octit     = 0-7
$hexit     = [$decdigit A-F a-f]
...
@numspc       = _*                   -- numeric spacer (#14473)
@decimal      = $decdigit(@numspc $decdigit)*
@binary       = $binit(@numspc $binit)*
@octal        = $octit(@numspc $octit)*
@hexadecimal  = $hexit(@numspc $hexit)*
@exponent     = @numspc [eE] [\-\+]? @decimal
@bin_exponent = @numspc [pP] [\-\+]? @decimal
```

Here, `$decdigit` is used for parsing decimal and hexadecimal literals (and their floating point variants), while `$digit` is used for the "numeric" part of alphanumeric identifiers.  The "ToDo" note makes it clear that this is a recognized deviation of GHC from the language standard.

So, you're reading the spec correctly, and GHC is semi-intentionally violating the spec.  There's an [open ticket](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/11609) that suggests at least documenting the deviation, but I don't think anyone's expressed any interest in fixing it.

Comment: All three of the deviations listed there are quite reasonable. I can see why there isn't a demand to "fix" them.